# How to Extract Collection elements with eclipse memory analyzer?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I am using Eclipse Memory Analyzer (version 1.4) for Java Heap dumps analysis. While the tool has a build in support to extract list items from a `java.util.List` and hash set values from a `java.util.HashSet` they lack similar support for `java.util.Collection`.

It will be helpful to share a ways to extract collection values, for example: values of `java.util.Queue`

Comment: What is your question, then?

Comment: Right, see question headline.